# What is the best practice for recording a run number into a Postgres database through a Python connection?

Tags: python, postgresql

Every few days I have to load around 50 rows of data into a Postgres 14 database through a Python script. As part of this I want to record a run number as a column in the db. This number should be the same for all rows I am inserting at that time and larger than any number currently in that column in the database, but other than that its actual value doesn't matter (ie, I need to make the number myself, I'm not just pulling it in from somewhere else).

The obvious way to do this would be with two calls from Python to the database - one to get the current max run number and one to save the data with the run number set to one more than the number retrieved in the first query. Is this best practice? Is there a better way to do this with only one call? Would people recommend making a function in postgres that does this instead and then call that function? I feel like this is likely a common situation with accepted best practice but I don't know what it is.

Comment: Don't make it a number make it a timestamp. In your script grab the current timestamp just before you do the insert and use that as the value for the run_time column in all the rows.

Comment: Ooh good call, I like that idea. Thanks!